# How to solve error , when in page `onChange` is not use in radio button Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I use this component for radio button , but when I don't use `Onchange`, I have the following error in page for `onUpdate` sometimes.

> TypeError: this.props.onUpdate is not a function

```
onChange(e) {
  let value = e.target.value;
  this.setState({value: value} );
}


render() {
  return (
    <div className="text-right mt-3">   
    {this.props.items.map(item => {
       return (    
          <label key={item.value}  className="c-radioLabel" htmlFor={item.value}>
            <input
              className="c-radio"
              type='radio'
              checked={this.state.value === item.value}
              disabled={item.disabled}
              value={item.value}
              name={this.props.name}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
              onClick={this.props.onClick} />
            <span className="mr-3 ">{item.label}</span>
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: So why don't you define a dummy function that doesn't do anything?

Comment: where is  your onUpdate function defined

Comment: <RadioButton
                            required
                            title="Test"
                            onUpdate={this.onChange}
                            ref="test"
                            items={[{value: "YES", label: "yes"}, {value: "NO", label: "no"}]}
                            name="opt-group3"
                            className="radio-group "
                        />

Comment: @Yossi because i use a lot this component

Comment: What is "onUpdate"? It's not a built-in JS function like onClick, you can't just call it like so

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to binding:

```
onChange = value => {
 //whatever you're doing with value.
}

render() {
  return (
    <RadioButton
       required
       title="Test"
       onUpdate={this.onChange}
       ref="test"
       items={[{value: "YES", label: "yes"}, {value: "NO", label: "no"}]} 
       name="opt-group3"
       className="radio-group"
     /> 
   )
}
```

And in the child component, change the bindings this way. Do not use `.bind(this)` in render. When render() is called, this.onChange.bind(this) will be invoked to bind the handler. Whenever state changes, this will keep generating a brand-new handlers!

```
onChange = (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ value: value }, () => this.props.onUpdate(value));
}


render() {
  return (
    <div className="text-right mt-3">   
    {this.props.items.map(item => {
       return (    
          <label key={item.value}  className="c-radioLabel" htmlFor={item.value}>
            <input
              className="c-radio"
              type='radio'
              checked={this.state.value === item.value}
              disabled={item.disabled}
              value={item.value}
              name={this.props.name}
              onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}
              onClick={this.props.onClick} />
            <span className="mr-3 ">{item.label}</span>
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You'll not face `this.props.onUpdate is not a function` error if the bindings are handled properly.